# Mui Select chooses the first option as selected when using grouping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Mui Select strangely selects the first option on it's first render when using grouping.

```
const generateOptions = useCallback((options: ISelectOption[]) => {
  return options.map((opt, ind) => {
    if (opt.groupOptions) {
      return [
        <ListSubheader key={opt.label}>{opt.label}</ListSubheader>,
        opt.groupOptions.map((val) => (
          <MenuItem key={ind} value={val.value}>{val.label}</MenuItem>
        ))
      ]
    }

    return (
      <MenuItem key={ind} value={opt.value}>{opt.label}</MenuItem>
    )
  })
}, [options])

<FormControl fullWidth className="fb">
  <InputLabel id="select-label">{label}</InputLabel>
  <Select
    name={name}
    value={value}
    label={label}
    disabled={disabled}
    id="select-label"
    labelId="select-label"
    multiple={!!multiple}
    IconComponent={IconComponent}
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    {generateOptions(options)}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

The options are an array of this shape.

```
interface ISelectOption {
  data?: any;
  label: string;
  className?: string;
  value: string | number;
  groupOptions?: ISelectOption[];
  renderOption?: (option: ISelectOption) => React.ReactNode;
}
```

And these are the Select options.

```
[
    {
        "label": "B2C campaigns",
        "value": "B2C campaigns",
        "groupOptions": [
            {
                "label": "Campaign 1",
                "value": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "B2B campaigns",
        "value": "B2B campaigns",
        "groupOptions": [
            {
                "label": "Campaign 2",
                "value": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The initial value of the `value` property is an empty string, but somehow Mui chooses the first option as selected. And this is clearly mentioned in the Mui docs.
[image]
[image: The element here has .Mui-Selected className]

When you remove the `<ListSubheader>` elements, you can see that it is starting to work as expected.

> The input value. Providing an empty string will select no options. Set
> to an empty string '' if you don't want any of the available options
> to be selected.

The version of Mui is

> "@mui/material": "^5.10.8",

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `defaultValue={value}` as well as `value={value}`, the default value is set only when the component is uncontrolled. This is mentioned in the `<Select />` api before the `value` description.

> The default value. Use when the component is not controlled.

Comment: I have edited my post and removed defaultValue.It wasn't a case as I left it there accidentally.I was trying anything I could and nothing helped.

Comment: Alright let me check.

Comment: Even Mui official codesandbox does it the same way - https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-leftpad-gx4vg4

Comment: Im confused, on initial select nothing is selected, what is the problem?

Comment: Check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-wildflower-4unoqs - in `demo.js`

Comment: I am confused too, I updated and added a screenshot of menu item having a `.Mui-selected` className.If you remove the `<ListSubheader>` elements, then it's starting to work correctly.

Comment: Nice hack to bypass the issue, thanks. It can be a good temporary solution.

Comment: I'll dig into this and if i find something i will post a comment here

Comment: did someone find anything ? the problem still occur and haven't find a solution on my side yet